# Getting Consistency

Tags: consistency

I have a few recipes that I want to reproduce *exactly the same* every time I brew them.  The ingredients are always the same, but many things affect the final outcome. **As an all-grain brewer, what tricks can I use to get consistent beer every time?**

Discuss compensating for factors such as

- Inconsistent crush
- Varying efficiencies
- %AA differences in hops

**I already have good temperature control during fermentation and mash.**

Answer (score 3):

I have found the two most significant effects on consistency both come from temperature.

1. Mash temperature.
2. Fermentation temperature.

The other factors certainly contribute but are simple to address through process, recipe etc.

The temperature variables however seem much harder for the home brewer to address. Strike temperature and water volume in the mash are so subject to ambient temperature that they are almost impossible to get right every time. Air temperature and amount of air movement (wind) impact the ability to heat a mash so significantly with propane that any attempt to address mash temps other than through insulation is fraught with variables you can't control.

Equally, on the fermentation side, the strength of the yeast strain, the pace of fermentation, the cellar ambient temperatures and the amount of heat produced by the yeast themselves all work to combat your best planned fermentation.

In order to address these, I am in the process of converting to an electric HERMS system to combat the hot side variables by mashing inside, using indirect heat and a PID controlled heating element to get the best temperature control I can obtain. On the cold side, I think the chest freezer or refrigerator based fermentation chamber is the only cost effective option for a home brewer. Lots of projects like these are well documented on HBT and other sites.

Comment: I completely agree with this.  Your first step is temperature control of fermentaion.  Once you have that nailed down you can build something to control your mash temperature. I am currently building a RIMS.

After that you can get into less obvious places for consistancy such as yeast pitching rate, disolved oxygen, ect.

Comment: I have a good grip on fermentation control with a chest freezer & an AC-powered coolbox. (These cold months limit my ale-making; good thing I like pilsners.) My mash temperature control is also coming along. I'd like to hear some ideas for making the same beer from varying ingredients.

Answer (score 2):

*Discuss compensating for factors such as:*

**Inconsistent crush**
 Invest in a better mill or inspect the one you have more closely.  A good mill should maintain a the same gap in it always.  Perhaps using a gap feeler to measure the gap each time would help here.

**Varying efficiencies**
 This comes from two places, first you need a consistent crush.  Next, you'll need to pay attention to batch to batch variation of your base malt.  This requires getting the malt analysis sheet for each lot of base malt you use.  If you are using the same 50lb sack of malt for a couple batches, then the variability is coming from your crush or your mash.  To overcome mash variabilities, you need to calculate your recipe for ~5% increase in final gravity than what you want.  That way if you want a 1.050OG you mash for a 1.055 and dilute the resultant wort preboil to 1.050OG.  Sometimes you'll get 1.057 others 1.052, but you'll always be able to adjust to 1.050 preboil.

**%AA differences in hops**
Obviously a good calculator for hopping rates is vital.  Variability in bitterness again comes from variation in gravities in the kettle too.  So strict gravity and volume readings is essential.  If your hop bill is all a single varietal of hop then its tough to replicate batch to batch if you don't use the same lot/farm of hops (i.e. bought in bulk)  But if you use a blend of hops to achieve each bitterness, flavor and aroma it becomes eaiser for the sublte variation to get smoothed out.  So that is more of a recipe thing than technique.

I have never had a lot of trouble with batch to batch variablitity.  But I tend to brew only a handful of recipes alot.  That is not the norm for homebrewers.  Most homebrewers rarely brew the same recipe twice. To really get consistent, you need to pick one recipe and brew it over and over.  I think consistancy comes from really knowing how to push your equipment.  We all tend to tweak and tweak and tweak.  But for consistancy you just need to brew over and over, changing very little. If you do that consistancy will come.